# Trouble with syntax for template-template-templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

I'm writing a meta-function `MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates`, used in the form

```
MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<Pack<Args...>, UnaryPredicates...>::type
```

so that a template pack of types will be multipartitioned by a pack `UnaryPredicates...` of unary predicates, with the partitions in the order of the unary predicates listed.  If you're not sure what I mean, just check out main() in the code below (which works correctly):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeInfo>

template <template <typename> class, typename, typename, typename> struct Helper;  

template <template <typename> class UnaryPredicate, template <typename...> class P, typename... Types1, typename... Types2>
struct Helper<UnaryPredicate, P<>, P<Types1...>, P<Types2...>> {
    using type = P<Types1..., Types2...>;
    using head = P<Types1...>;
    using tail = P<Types2...>;
};

template <template <typename> class UnaryPredicate, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Types1, typename... Types2>
struct Helper<UnaryPredicate, P<First, Rest...>, P<Types1...>, P<Types2...>> : std::conditional<UnaryPredicate<First>::value,
        Helper<UnaryPredicate, P<Rest...>, P<Types1..., First>, P<Types2...>>,
        Helper<UnaryPredicate, P<Rest...>, P<Types1...>, P<Types2..., First>>
    >::type {};

template <typename, template <typename> class> struct PartitionWithUnaryPredicate;

template <template <typename> class UnaryPredicate, template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct PartitionWithUnaryPredicate<P<Ts...>, UnaryPredicate> : Helper<UnaryPredicate, P<Ts...>, P<>, P<>> {};

template <typename, template <typename> class...> struct MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates;

template <typename Pack, template <typename> class UnaryPredicate>
struct MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<Pack, UnaryPredicate> : PartitionWithUnaryPredicate<Pack, UnaryPredicate> {};

template <typename, typename> struct Join;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types1, typename... Types2>
struct Join<P<Types1...>, P<Types2...>> {
    using type = P<Types1..., Types2...>;
};

//template <template <typename, template <typename> class> class Pack, typename... Ts>
//struct JoinSpecial : Join<typename Pack::head, typename MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<typename Pack::tail, Ts...>::type> {};

template <typename Pack, template <typename> class First, template <typename> class... Rest>
struct MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<Pack, First, Rest...> : Join<typename PartitionWithUnaryPredicate<Pack, First>::head, typename MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<typename PartitionWithUnaryPredicate<Pack, First>::tail, Rest...>::type> {};
// The above can be improved, since PartitionWithUnaryPredicate<Pack, First> is being computed twice.

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Testing:

template <typename...> struct Pack {};

template <typename Last>
struct Pack<Last> {
    static void print() {std::cout << typeid(Last).name() << std::endl;}
};

template <typename First, typename ... Rest>
struct Pack<First, Rest...> {
    static void print() {std::cout << typeid(First).name() << ' ';  Pack<Rest...>::print();}
};

struct Thing {};
struct Blob { Blob(Blob&&){} };  // Copy constructor deleted.
struct Object {};
enum MyEnum {x, y, z};
enum HerEnum {xx, yy, zz};

int main() {
    MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<Pack<int, Thing, double, short, Blob, char, MyEnum, long, Object, float, HerEnum>,
        std::is_integral>::type b;
    b.print();  // int short char long Thing double Blob MyEnum Object float HerEnum

    MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<Pack<int, Thing, double, short, Blob, char, MyEnum, long, Object, float, HerEnum>,
        std::is_integral, std::is_enum>::type c;
    c.print();  // int short char long MyEnum HerEnum Thing double Blob Object float

    MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<Pack<int, Thing, double, short, Blob, char, MyEnum, long, Object, float, HerEnum>,
        std::is_integral, std::is_enum, std::is_arithmetic>::type d;
    d.print();  // int short char long MyEnum HerEnum double float Thing Blob Object

    MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<Pack<int, Thing, double, short, Blob, char, MyEnum, long, Object, float, HerEnum>,
        std::is_integral, std::is_enum, std::is_arithmetic, std::is_member_pointer, std::is_copy_constructible>::type e;
    e.print();  // int short char long MyEnum HerEnum double float Thing Object Blob
}
```

The problem is trying to refine the above code.

```
PartitionWithUnaryPredicate<Pack, First>
```

is being computed twice, I'm trying to define `JoinSpecial` that will use it just once. But I can't get the syntax correct.

```
template <template <typename, template <typename> class> class Pack, typename... Ts>
struct JoinSpecial : Join<typename Pack::head, typename MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<typename Pack::tail, Ts...>::type> {};
```

does not compile.  The template type `PartitionWithUnaryPredicate` is of type `template <typename, template <typename> class> class` is it not?

**Update:**
Thanks to Angew's tip, I got the syntax correct now:

```
template <template <typename, template <typename> class> class P, typename Pack, template <typename> class Pred, template <typename> class... Ts>
struct JoinSpecial : Join<typename P<Pack, Pred>::head, typename MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<typename P<Pack, Pred>::tail, Ts...>::type> {};

template <typename Pack, template <typename> class First, template <typename> class... Rest>
struct MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<Pack, First, Rest...> : JoinSpecial<PartitionWithUnaryPredicate, Pack, First, Rest...> {};
```

Now everything works correctly--my first time using template-template-templates, which I must say looks quite ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition of `JoinSpecial`, `Pack` is a class template. Then, in specifying template arguments to `Join`, you have `typename Pack::head` and `typename Pack::tail`. But `Pack` is a template, not a class — you need to supply template arguments for `Pack`.

Comment: Ok, so the exact sytax I need is `template <template <typename, template <typename> class> class P, typename Pack, template <typename> class Pred, template <typename> class... Ts>
struct JoinSpecial : Join<typename P<Pack, Pred>::head, typename MultipartitionWithUnaryPredicates<typename P<Pack, Pred>::tail, Ts...>::type> {};`  Whew!  Template-template-templates.